# No wall for plumbing vent, so I have this contraption. Is the mechanical connection needed?

Tags: plumbing

Everything about this rig seems to be in order. The sink worked for two years, so I’m just going to reuse it. It appears that I’m not the first person to dig into this.

Is the mechanical fastener serving any purpose? Other than maybe someone didn’t want to pull the sink but needed to make a repair.

And if you know about how this works, does the height matter? If my sink is deeper, or more shallow, does this device need to raise or lower? I’ll make a new one if I need to make adjustments.

[image]

Comment: So pretty much the visible part of an "island sink" venting installation if you are looking up  references/your applicable code.. Got  a picture from the underside of the floor?

Comment: The larger the loop the better they work. We used to make loops before AAV’s were allowed  we never used the rubber coupling possibly it was for a repair.

Comment: In your area, check if the electricity outlet is permitted this close or under the sink. Not allowed in my area (Australia).